# Is it possible to install Linux after installing windows?

Tags: linux, installation, multi-boot

I would like to know if it is possible to install Linux based OS with an already installed Windows.

If not then why?

Comment: What would you assume? ;)

Comment: yes. You can replace Windows, run both together with duel boot or create a virtual machine for Linux. Lots of guides on doing this. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes. You should install a linux distro in another partition, it will most probably install alternative bootloader because windows' bootloader doesn't recognize linux. After that if it didn't automatically, you should configure the bootloader. Google each step, there are lits of information in the web.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this. Most Linux distributions will recognize the Windows system and will ask you what to do.

You can overwrite the existing Windows system.

or

You can add a new partition for Linux.

You should have free space for a new Partition. If thats not the case, try shrinking the existing windows partition before. You can do that with a tool like the GParted live cd: http://gparted.org/livecd.php